# mergesort and java implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose I want to use the mergesort algorithm.
Does JAVA has a method/function which implements the mergesort algorithm?

Or do I have to "manually" code the algorithm?

I do not know JAVA at all.

Comment: Java (that's no acronym) is just a programming language. It doesn't have anything but the most primitive building blocks. There are, however, various Java libraries. Are you by chance asking for existing merge sort implementations written in Java?

Comment: @delnan Java uses mergesort in its Sort method (`Arrays` and `Collections` classes).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza My pedantic point is that JDK != Java language. Also, AFAIK that's timsort, which, while heavily based on mergesort, is quite different. (At least different enough to warrant a name, a wikipedia page, and its own set of explanatory blog posts.)

Comment: @delnan check the `Collection#sort` JavaDoc, posted in Reimeus's answer: *Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative **mergesort**.* So, every JDK *must* use mergesort to implement it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have seen it (and now that I followed it, I recalled that they started using timsort only with version 7). Also note that I *never* claimed there aren't merge sort implementations in the JDK. I don't see how this note would require any specific implementation, as long as it is a stable sort. It's not like any Java program could ever determine the difference, right?

Comment: @delnan sorry I can't go in a chat room in this pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is [Arrays.sort (Object[] )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29), there is a [source code sample](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29) from OpenJDK

Comment: So, need to manually code anything. From the moment I call arrays.sort in Java, under the hood, mergesort(modified) is working to achieve results

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

> The sorting algorithm is a modified mergesort (in which the merge is omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the lowest element in the high sublist). This algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n) performance.

Answer (score -2):

No there isn't a merge sort out of the box. A simple google after 'java mergesort' should give you plenty of useful results

Comment: You must read the JavaDoc or investigate before post when you don't know the answer.

Comment: And the top google result is wikipedia which mentions that Java Array.sort implements merge sort.